# Prove a level set of a function in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is not a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1^2+x_2^2 - x_3^2 - x_4^2$$

I need to show that $S = f^{-1}(0)$ is not a smooth manifold.

I was able to show that $S$ is not an embedded submanifold by identifying the tangent spaces $T_{p} S$ with subspaces of $T_{p} \mathbb{R}^4$ and showing that $T_{\mathbf{0}} S$ is 4-dimensional while $T_p S$ is not. However, I'm not sure I can use that to say anything about $S$ itself. I'm not sure how I would show the tangent spaces of $S$ vary dimension for any possible smooth structure on $S$ unrelated to how $S$ sits in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I'm now trying to show a neighborhood of the origin is not locally Euclidean. I've seen exercises where one shows $\{(x,y) : x^2 = y^2\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is not a manifold by showing that a neighborhood of the origin leaves 4 connected components when you remove the origin, but I haven't been able to rigourously justify similar reasoning here.

Answer (score 2):

In short $S$ is a cone over torus. To see this, consider intersection with ${S}^3$, you'll get $\{(x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3,\,x_4)| x_1^2+x_2^2=0.5,\,x_3^2+x_4^2=0.5\}$, which is ${S}^1\times{S}^1$. thus $S$ is the union of straight lines those passing through origin and a point on the torus.

Now if $S$ is smooth, intersecting with ${S}^3$ of radius that is small enough will get ${S}^2$, which is contradictory. (this argument is a bit hand-waving, use the dimension of tangent space might be better)

Answer (score 0):

$T_0S$ is not defined (unless you talk about notions like the Zariski tangent space). You’re talking about the kernel of the derivative of $f$, of course, but failure of the hypotheses of the implicit function theorem does not, working over the reals, guarantee failure to be a manifold.

Cones (that are not linear) are not manifolds because of their cone points. If $0\in S$ has a neighborhood diffeomorphic (or, indeed, homeomorphic) to a $3$-ball, then that neighborhood must remain connected if you remove $0$. But it does not.